# Using the comparison test to determine the convergence of these series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm given the following problem:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{k}}{1+k^2}$

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-\pi)^2}$

I'm asked to solve these using the comparison test, however I'm unable to determine a suitable comparison. How does one choose such a series? Is there a technique that can be used, in general?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For the first, we have

$$(\forall k\ge 1)\; 1+k^2\ge k^2$$
and
$$\frac{1}{1+k^2}\le \frac{1}{k^2}$$

So, $$\frac{\sqrt{k}}{1+k^2}\le \frac{1}{k^{\frac 32}}$$

For the second,

$$(\forall k\ge 8) \;\; k-\pi\ge \frac k2$$

and
$$\frac{1}{(k-\pi)^2}\le \frac{4}{k^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, we have that

$$\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^2+1}<\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k^2}=\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}$$

For the second one, we have that

$$\frac{1}{(k-\pi)^2}=\frac{1}{k^2-2k\pi +\pi^2}<\frac{1}{k^2-2k\pi}$$

note that for $k\geq 13$ we have
$$\frac{k}{2}>2\pi $$

This implies

$$\frac{1}{k^2-2k\pi}<\frac{1}{k^2-k\frac{k}{2}}=\frac{2}{k^2}$$